# Calling a Scalar-valued Function in SSIS

Tags: ssis, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

Is there any way to execute a scalar-valued function from within a Derived Column transformation in SSIS?

-Scenario-

I have a function in my source DB that converts weights based on a UOM value in the record's UOM column. I want to utilize this function in the ETL process to ensure that my weight measures are always pounds. Can I call this function from within a Derived Column? If not, is there another transformation task I could utilize within the Data Flow (trying to avoid staging columns)?

**dbo.Tasks table**

```
id |  Name  | netWeight | grossWeight | UOM
12   Task12     30000        50000      10
```

**dbo.MeasurementUnits table**

```
id |   Name    | Shortname | Type | Precision
12  Kilogram    kg          3   10000       
14  Pound       lb          3   10000
```

**dbo.GetConvertedWeight function**

```
    ALTER  FUNCTION [dbo].[GetConvertedWeight](@iWeight money, @ifromUOM int, @iToUOM int) 
    RETURNS money
    AS  
    BEGIN 
    DECLARE @lConvertedWeight money, 
            @lKgToGrams money,
            @lLbToGrams money,
            @lOzToGrams money,
            @lWeightInGrams money

    --convert the weight to grams first.
    SELECT @lWeightInGrams = CASE WHEN @iFromUOM = 12 THEN (ISNULL(@iWeight,0) * 1000)
                         WHEN @iFromUOM = 14 THEN (ISNULL(@iWeight,0) * 453.5924)
                         WHEN @iFromUOM = 15 THEN (ISNULL(@iWeight,0) * 28.3495)
                         WHEN @iFromUOM = 13 THEN (ISNULL(@iWeight,0))
                         ELSE ISNULL(@iWeight,0)
                         END

    --Convert the converted weight to grams to the desired weight
    SELECT @lConvertedWeight = CASE WHEN @iToUOM = 12 THEN (ISNULL(@lWeightInGrams,0) / 1000)
                            WHEN @iToUOM = 13 THEN ISNULL(@lWeightInGrams,0)
                            WHEN @iToUOM = 14 THEN (ISNULL(@lWeightInGrams,0)/453.5924)
                            WHEN @iToUOM = 15 THEN (ISNULL(@lWeightInGrams,0) / 28.3495 )
                            ELSE (ISNULL(@lWeightInGrams,0)/453.5924)
                            END
RETURN @lConvertedWeight
```

**Example function call**

```
dbo.GetConvertedWeight(dbo.Tasks.netWeight, dbo.Tasks.weightUOM, 14) AS netWeight
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.  What you'll want is an [OLE DB Command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141138.aspx) to do that.  Send the results to an Output Column, and life should be peachy keen for you--at least with regards to SSIS.

Comment: After hours of work (and finally just modifying that function and changing it into a procedure) I finally got this solution to work. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction ;-)